# jquery remote validation, what would be the php code?

Tags: php, jquery

I am using bassistance validation plugin and I need to check if the email already exists in my database, can someone please provide a sample php code for the serverside portion of this? i don't simply want to echo true or false, i want the json solution with the message option too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't include the database connection stuff, but figured you would not need that? If you do let me know and I'll provide that as well.

```
<?php

require_once('dbconnection.php');

$email = $_GET['email'];    
mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);
$q = "SELECT Email FROM Users WHERE Email= '" . $email . "'";
$r = mysqli_query($conn, $q) or die(mysqli_error());
$totalRows = mysqli_num_rows($r);

if( $totalRows > 0 )
{
    //email already exists in database, return false.
    echo "false";

} else {
    echo "true";
}

mysqli_free_result($r); //close connection
```

?>

Comment: I just realized you didn't want the regular echo solution...but I'll leave it in case someone else does.

Comment: I looked at the validation plugin documentation to see how it would even work without using true or false. This is from the site: 
"Added support for ajax-validation, see method “remote”; serverside returns JSON, true for valid elements, false or a String for invalid, String is used as message "